# Wordpress 404 on Posts with New Categories

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

My Wordpress site with links from other sites to my blog posts. These blog posts did not have the category in the URL, but now they do. So the following link to my site fails.

```
domain.com/blog/post-name
```

Now, the same post can be found here:

```
domain.com/blog/category-name/post-name
```

My permalink structure is `/blog/%category%/%postname%` and it gives me a 404 error. Does Wordpress not search for the slug "post-name" regardless of category? Any ideas on how to redirect these or resolve these posts. I have hundreds of posts that are now 404.

Yes, I have saved the Settings > Permalinks page.

Comment: Does this URL throwing an error as well? `domain.com/category-name/post-name`

Comment: Yes. I ended up putting a temporary fix using the [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin and catching all of the `/blog` posts.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Created a new one by clicking on save button in Settings->Permalinks

Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all. Paste on .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**2)** Enable to mod_rewrite:

**sudo a2enmod rewrite**

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already in effect. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache:

**3)** Go to this file just change "AllowOverride None" to AllowOverride all

sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
```

**sudo service apache2 restart**

and now that pages started working fine...